# how to insert JSON data into MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert the json data I am getting from the yelp api into mysql database.it only inserts the text and the rating of the first review in the json data. Does not insert the profile url or name as well as the other reviews i am getting back.

```
$response = json_decode($data, true);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','reviews');

if($response){
    $text = isset($response ['reviews'][0]['text']) ? $response ['reviews' ][0]['text'] : "";
    $rating = isset($response ['reviews'][0]['rating']) ? $response ['reviews'][0]['rating'] : "";
    $url = isset($response ['reviews'][0]['users'][1]['profile_url']) ? $response ['reviews'][0]['users'][1]['profile_url'] : "";
    $name = isset($response ['reviews'][0]['users'][1]['name']) ? $response ['reviews'][0]['users'][1]['name'] : "";

    foreach ($response as $value){
        $query = "INSERT INTO yelp (Text, Rating, ProfileURL, Name)
    VALUES('$text', '$rating', '$name', '$url')";
        
        mysqli_query($con,$query);
    
    }
}

echo "Data Inserted Successfully";
```

Comment: Can you show a sample of the JSON?

Comment: If you want to insert more than just the first review, you need a loop `foreach ($response['reviews'] AS $review) ...`

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment. And use jsonlint.com to format it readably.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You *really* shouldn't use string concatenation to put values into SQL queries, as it opens up your site to a lot of vulnerabilities. Google PHP Prepared Statements for a safer option.

Comment: Typo: `['users']` should be `['user']`

Comment: `user` is not an array, you don't need to index it with `[1]`.

Comment: okay so i got it to insert the url and name, but still only inserts the first review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over all the reviews. I'll also show how to do it using a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO yelp (Text, Rating, ProfileURL, Name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("siss", $text, $rating, $profile_url, $name);

foreach ($response['reviews'] as $review) {
    $text = $review['text'] ?? '';
    $rating = $review['rating'] ?? 0;
    $profile_url = $review['user']['profile_url'] ?? '';
    $name = $review['user']['name'] ?? '';

    $stmt->execute();
}
```